# ResultSet is closed, only prints the first "SUBKATEGORI"

Tags: java, netbeans

Im running the code and keep getting the Resultset is closed, is there something wrong with the loops? The Strings that is taken from the for() has multiple "SUBKATEGORIER" aswell. Pls help me I'm new to Java.

```java
Object[] valt = jList1.getSelectedValues();

for (Object ettVal : valt) {
    String enSuperkategori = ettVal.toString();
    System.out.println(enSuperkategori);

    try {
        Statement stmt2 = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery("SELECT SUBKATEGORIID FROM 
SUBKATEGORI JOIN SUPERKATEGORI ON SUPERKATEGORI.SUPERKATEGORIID = 
SUBKATEGORI.SUPERKATEGORI WHERE SUPERKATEGORI.SKNAMN ='" + enSuperkategori 
+"'");

        while(rs2.next());
        {
        PreparedStatement ps2 = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT 
INTO ANVANDARE_SUBKATEGORI (ANVANDARE,SUBKATEGORI) VALUES(?,?)");
        ps2.setString(1, angivetAnv);
        ps2.setInt(2, rs2.getInt("SUBKATEGORIID"));
        System.out.println(rs2.getInt("SUBKATEGORIID"));
        ps2.executeUpdate();
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact cause of the error, but my guess is that your first result set is getting closed as soon as you run the inner insert.  The good news is that you may run your entire insert using the following single query:

```
INSERT INTO ANVANDARE_SUBKATEGORI (ANVANDARE, SUBKATEGORI)
SELECT SUBKATEGORIID, SUBKATEGORIID
FROM SUBKATEGORI s
INNER JOIN SUPERKATEGORI sp
    ON sp.SUPERKATEGORIID = s.SUPERKATEGORI
WHERE sp.SKNAMN = ?
```

Your relevant Java code:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO ANVANDARE_SUBKATEGORI (ANVANDARE, SUBKATEGORI) ";
sql += "SELECT SUBKATEGORIID, SUBKATEGORIID ";
sql += "FROM SUBKATEGORI s ";
sql += "INNER JOIN SUPERKATEGORI sp ";
sql += "ON sp.SUPERKATEGORIID = s.SUPERKATEGORI ";
sql += "WHERE sp.SKNAMN = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, enSuperkategori);
ps.executeUpdate();
```